# How to fetch column names runtime

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My **MySQL database** has column names like clnt_1001,clnt_1002 .... so how can I fetch the value from all clients runtime? ,

where clients can be added later,
like `where column name like '%CLNT_%' and id =2001;`(all values in 'CLNT_' are integers)

Comment: What does "clnt" stands for and what is the meaning of the number in "clnt_1001" and "clnt_1002"? And how do you generate the columns?

Comment: clnt stands for my Clients, adding every client alter my quantity table like Clnt_1001 for first client upto N,where i store quantity of material hold by that client @Progman

Comment: Dynamic generation of columns/tables is a sign of bad table design. Convert your table design to 3NF to make your life easier for handling the data in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to get the column names and use it in your `SELECT` query, e.g.:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
AND COLUMN_NAME like 'CLNT_%';
```

This will give you (comma separated) column names, you can then use the result of this query to construct the `SELECT` query, e.g.:

```
SELECT <columns> 
FROM your_table;
```

Here, you can replace `<columns>` with result of the first query and get the data for all the columns.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) MySQL documentation on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables.

Comment: so here GROUP_CONCAT(CLNT_) will retrive all columns starting with 'CLNT_' ??